# Visual studio 2010 and Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express, visual-studio-2010

Do visual studio 2010 include already Sql Server instance, or I need to install Sql Server developer edition to develop an application that need a Sql Server db.

If it installs a Sql Server express edition, it this enough or it's better to have Sql Server developer edition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would second that installing the "full" SQL Server Development Edition makes sense if you do serious database development.

However you can have both installed side by side, and having SQL Server Express is very useful for one reason - it supports placing database files in the `App_Data` folder of ASP.NET applications. While I don't do this for my own projects, it's a very nice feature for demos or open source applications you download from the web: just unzip, start VS, hit F5, and you have a running solution including database. Without SQL Express, you first have to move the MDF file, attach the database, set up user rights, replace the connection strings etc...

Answer (score 7):

The Visual Studio 2010 installer gives you the option of installing SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.  This edition of SQL Server is good enough for development purposes but is not intended for production use.

Comment: Is it more convenient to use Management Studio for manipulate the DB, or Server Explorer is enough?

Comment: I strongly prefer management studio myself, but others like visual studio.  Also, if lure really going to do heavy db development, I recommend forgoing SQL Express and installing SQL Developer Edition.

Comment: @Dave I totally agree, I feel exactly the same. But installing visual studio have a resources cost. and I don't really familiar with the Express edition, so maybe is it worth a try?

Comment: Express will do you fine for small DBs, but it has a size limitation.  Additionally, it does not support restoring all types of databases that can come from a Standard or Enterprise edition DB, should you need to do that, because there are certain features which are enabled only in Enterprise/Developer edition.  Just cut the amount of RAM SQL Server uses after you install it, and you will be fine on resources.

Comment: The size limitation is now 10Gb.

Answer (score 2):

I think the size limitation is not the main issue.
In Sql Server 2008 you have some features in Sql Server Management Studio that aren't available in the Express management Studio or the Express database engine, like:
- suggesting the table and column names (in Query Window)
- Sql profiler
Cor Westra