# Does Visual Studio 2010 come with sql server express

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi
I installed VS 2010 and sql server management studio 2008 express. I full installed VS but I can't find a sql server. Do I need to download and install sql server express on my PC? I have Windows 7 64 bit and I installed server management studio 2008 express x86

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466564/visual-studio-2010-and-sql-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that VS2010 installs sql server 2008 express

It does install sql server express but you need to enable sql browsing. You need to go to sql server configuration manager->sql server services->sql server browsing and enable it

[Visual studio 2010 and Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466564/visual-studio-2010-and-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Management Studio is the tool used to connect to a SQL Server instance.  It does not necessarily install a SQL Server instance on your machine.

If you have the DVD you will need to install the full instance.  If you don't have the full SQL Server DVD, then you'll need to buy it or download SQL Server Express free from http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Comment: I was told by a colleague that installing VS2010  will install sql server express. How would I figure out if sql server express in installed.